# Filtering FORFILES in batch files

Tags: postgresql, windows, powershell, batch-file, server

I'm trying to write a batch file to run on Task Scheduler on Windows server to delete some PostgreSQL archived files.

Thought I use FORFILES and the following will list all the .backup files in the archived folders.

```
SET "log=%USERPROFILE%\temp\delete.log"
SET "target.dir=\\UNC_path\pgsql_arch"

pushd "%target.dir%"
FORFILES /S /D -30 /M *.backup /C "cmd /c echo @file"
popd
```

The *.backup file is a 1kb and in PostgreSQL, it looks like information of what the backup contains. I do not want to delete those - what I'm trying to get is the the last file of the 30th day so I can pass into `pg_archivecleanup` to let it do its thing.

For example, today is 2/22/2024 - so essentially I'm trying to get the .backup filename for 1/21/2024 to pass into `pg_archivecleanup` to delete all archived files older than 1/21/2024.

Question, is it possible to filter the list that FORFILES returns to just 1 single filename? If so, how can I do that?

I welcome any other suggestions. This is windows and it's a single PostgreSQL to support 3rd party vendor product.

Thank you

Tried

```
SET "log=%USERPROFILE%\temp\delete.log"
SET "target.dir=\\UNC_path\pgsql_arch"

pushd "%target.dir%"
FORFILES /S /D -30 /M *.backup /C "cmd /c echo @file"
popd
```

Expecting:
Need just single row from FORFILES results.

Comment: Have trouble with dates on Powershell   `$Targetdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
        Get-ChildItem -Path "\\uncpath\" -Recurse -filter *.backup | Select Name | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $Targetdate}`  No results returned.  Thinking it's datetime issue, also tried `$Targetdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Get-ChildItem -Path "\\uncpath\" -Recurse -filter *.backup | Select Name | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") -ge $Targetdate}`  Got error *You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.*

Comment: Following will return everything as if the Where-Object isn't even there. `Get-ChildItem -Path "\\uncpath\" -Recurse -filter *.backup | Select Name | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-14) }`

Comment: You cannot filter on `LastWriteTime` after `Select Name`, since the former property will no longer be present; instead, place `SelectName` _last_.

Comment: mklement0: Thank you so much. That solved that problem. Gosh - where were you 3 hours ago? Thank you SO MUCH.

Comment: @Student :) glad to hear my comment helped.

Comment: I'm not sure that using a specifc 'number of days ago' in the comments above, really highlights the major benefit of my PowerShell advice. That is determining the date of one calendar month and one day ago. Example: ```(Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).AddMonths(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')```.

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be a bit tricky, because you probably want the newest of your outdated files. `FORFILES` returns an unsorted list of files, so you cannot just get the first line only.

Here is what I came up with to achieve the sorting using two file listings and cross-matching them. It would be easier to use `SORT`, but this suffers from different locales for the date (i.e. 22.02.2024 vs 2/22/2024).

```
@echo off 

set ext=*.backup
set age=-30

rem clear temporary files
if exist allfiles.txt del allfiles.txt
if exist forfiles.txt del forfiles.txt
if exist oldfiles.txt del oldfiles.txt

rem get a list of files sorted by time (newest first)
dir /b /od %ext% >allfiles.txt

rem get an unsorted list of files older than X 
forfiles /D %age% /M %ext% >forfiles.txt 

rem loop through the files and check for a match
for /f "delims=" %%B in (allfiles.txt) do ( 
  findstr /C:"%%B" forfiles.txt >>oldfiles.txt
)

rem get only the first line of our sorted matches
for /f "delims=" %%A in (oldfiles.txt) do (
   echo %%A
   exit /b
   rem this causes the loop to run only once
)

rem clear temporary files
if exist allfiles.txt del allfiles.txt
if exist forfiles.txt del forfiles.txt
if exist oldfiles.txt del oldfiles.txt

rem unset variables
set age=
set ext=
```

Feel free to add any degree of complexity, i.e. by inlining the `DIR` command into the `FOR` statement. You might also reduce this to run in a single loop by checking the output of `FINDSTR` directly. Unfortunately, it does not return an `ERRORLEVEL` that would give an indication of whether there was a match or not...

Creating three temporary files is surely not the most elegant way to solve this, but this approach seemed fairly straightforward to me.

PS: If you want to check if the sorting is correct, just insert `echo %%~tB >>oldfiles.txt` after the `findstr` command.

Comment: @Student,
I read the comments above, noticing that I posted my answer just two minutes before you replied about the PowerShell solution. This is great, if it works for you. I would still be happy about some feedback here.

Comment: @matried: I apologize for the slow response and appreciate your attempts. I added your scripts to my batch and changed the days to -5 for smaller result sets for testing. Anyway, the results did return 1 row. However, the row it returned was the 1st row which was Jan 11th 2024 file. I changed `SET age=-14` and it still returns the 1st row / Jan 11th 2024 file. I closed out my command prompt session, with `SET age=-14` and reran the .bat and it still returns the Jan 11th 2024 filename. I will try to comment out the clear temporary files section when I get a chance to see if I can find anything.

Comment: @matried: Should this `rem loop through the files and check for a match
for /f "delims=" %%B in (allfiles.txt) do (findstr /C:"%%B" forfiles.txt >>oldfiles.txt
)` be looking for matching lines? If allfiles.txt is getting a list of all *.backup files, and forfiles.txt list filtered by # of days files; shouldn't we be getting the 1st file that doesn't match to allfiles.txt? As is, forfiles.txt has the same rows as oldfiles.txt.

Comment: @matried: Feel free if you want to pursue the batch file path. I think it'll be helpful to have options to contribute to PostgreSQL in Windows that I have found to be very limited. I'll test on my Dev which I have daily data sets I can test with (SLA is to keep 7 days of archived files and at this time I have 30 days in Dev).

Comment: @Student sorry for the slow response on my side as well...  The first loop does not filter, but it assures the order of files is the same as in allfiles.txt (which was sorted using DIR /OD). I tested it on my side using some *.pdf files in my downloads folder that were >600 days old. It is possible that FORFILES already gives the right order on your machine, but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Final working script in Powershell for future visitors to clean PostgreSQL Archived Location if you don't have replicas. Hope it helps someone.

```
Clear-Host
$archdir='\\uncpath\pgsql_arch'
$filename= Get-ChildItem -Path $archdir -filter *.backup | 
           Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |
           Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-31) -and -not $_.PSIsContainer} | 
           Select -ExpandProperty Name -last 1 
Write-Output "$archdir $filename"
$script="$archdir $filename"
Start-Process -FilePath "Your_PostgreSQL_bin_path\pg_archivecleanup.exe" -ArgumentList "-d $script" -Wait
```

Comment: Nice; a few tips: If you add `-File` to `Get-ChildItem`, you don't need `-and -not $_.PSIsContainer` later. Unless `pg_archivecleanup.exe` happens to be a GUI application with a CLI (which is rare), it is simpler to invoke it directly, which is synchronous by default: `& "Your_PostgreSQL_bin_path\pg_archivecleanup.exe" -d $script`. You may need to post the comment addressed to matried on _their_ answer for them to see it.